# How to remove default lines on BIRT cross-tab object

Tags: birt

The report output i have calls for no-column lines.

I'm using a crosstab to generate the data i need, however BIRT crosstabs seem to auto-include its own formatting, namely, gray cell borders. i can't seem to find where to remove these.

How to remove the birt crosstab cell borders?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your report in BIRT report designer, and select Outline view (if not available, select Window > Show View > Outline from the menu).

Expand the Styles node - this should include both crosstab and crosstab-cell styles. Delete these two styles.

Preview the report - the lines should now be removed from the crosstab.

Comment: yep! i ended up finding my own solution and that was to edit the xml directly clearing the lines.

Comment: and after looking a bit closer i notice the styles are there for editing. geez, i feel blind.